# i have a ListView Builder and i want to place a List of TextEditingController in a List

Tags: flutter

i have a ListView Builder and i want to place a List of TextEditingController in a List.But it give an Error,"Expected to find an Identifier".Im confused.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ListViewBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListViewBuilder({super.key});

  @override
  State<ListViewBuilder> createState() => _ListViewBuilderState();
}

class _ListViewBuilderState extends State<ListViewBuilder> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  // final TextEditingController controller;
  List validators = [
    (value) {
      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please enter the number';
      }
      return null;
    },
    (value) {
      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please enter the email';
      }
      return null;
    },
    (value) {
      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please enter the password';
      }
      return null;
    },
  ];
  List formatters = [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-zA-Z]')),
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'[/\\]'))
  ];
    ///Error happens here!!
  List controller = [
  final _name = TextEditingController();
  final _age = TextEditingController();
  final _height = TextEditingController();
  final _color = TextEditingController();
  final _dateofBirt = TextEditingController();
  final _Nationality = TextEditingController();

  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 3,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return TextFormField(
              controller: controller[index],
              validator: validators[index],
              inputFormatters: [formatters[index]],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Click'),
        onPressed: () {
          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            // If the form is valid, display a snackbar. In the real world,
            // you'd often call a server or save the information in a database.
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i made a controller a variable.and also tried assigning them individually but still the error appears.

Comment: `List controller = List.generate(6, (i) => TextEditingController());`

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use list of `TextEditingController`  you dont need to assign it on separate variable.

```dart
  List controller = [
    TextEditingController(),
    TextEditingController(),
    TextEditingController(),
    TextEditingController(),
    TextEditingController(),
    TextEditingController(),
  ];
```

You can also use `List.generate` for it.

Now to get `_name` as you've define on 1st item, you need to use index like `controller[0]` for _name. `_age` for `controller[1]` ,, so on.

You can get text like

`controller[index].text`

Comment: Thank you but can you write that in a sample code'"controller[index].text"

Comment: how do like to get text ?

Comment: from the user input or are you if im getting the question correct,should i pass it in the SubmitButton onPressed function eg{  _name:_controller[0].text,
                          _ager: _controller[1].text,

Comment: on `FloatingActionButton` ? Let's say your comment is the sequence, so you can get text of `yearOfManufature` using `controller[0].text` , `yearofmanufacture` => `controller[1].text` ... index is the squence it would be easy if you've include hint text